# Plotting a system response imaginary part as a function of omega(w) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, signals, signal-processing

I am trying to plot the following :

Im{X (e^jω)} = -a * sin(w) / (1 - 2*a*cos(w) + a^2) , where -1 < a < 0.

I am trying to plot it as a function of w.
but for some reason I get only the line with 0 dots all along the y axes without any meaningful graph.

What is the best way to plot this function using Matlab?

Also how to properly plot a phase response if my response looks like this:

phase (X (ejω)) = tan^-1(-a*sin(w)/ 1 - a*cos(w)).

When I use angle() function the matlab throws error that X must be same length as Y. I am wondering if I do have to use functions such as imag() and angle() or just stem it without it.
Currently my code is as follows:

```
a = -0.2;
N = 10;
w = -2*pi:2*pi/N:2*pi;
x_imag = - a.* sin(w)./(1 - 2 * a*cos(w) + a^2);
stem(w, imag(x_imag), 'filled')
x_phase = inv(tan(-a.*sin(w)./(1- a.*cos(w))))
stem(w, angle(x_phase), 'filled')
```

Where do I have a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

```
Im{X (e^jω)} = -a * sin(w) / (1 - 2*a*cos(w) + a^2) , where -1 < a < 0.
```

is the imaginary part of the equation, `x_imag = - a.* sin(w)./(1 - 2 * a*cos(w) + a^2);` doesn't have any imaginary part i.e. there's no `i` or `j` in the equation. For example consider the complex number:

```
c = 2 + 2i
% the imaginary part is 2 <- no i
```

Thus when you try to plot the `imag` of `x_imag` you will get all zeros since there's no imaginary part. In other words, just plot `x_imag` as is:

```
stem(w, x_imag, 'filled')
```

To get the phase of the number you need tan^-1 which in matlab is atan ([inv](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html) is matrix inverse). Thus:

```
x_phase = atan(-a.*sin(w)./(1- a.*cos(w)))
stem(w, x_phase, 'filled')
```

Comment: Thank you @StaticBeagle, you resolved my doubts, I get it now. Also , for tan part, instead of atan() I used 1./tan and got the same answer. So I guess both options work fine.

Comment: @ViniLL glad I could help. One thing though, tan^-1 aka atan() is not mathematically equivalent to 1/tan (cot() in Matlab), you might be getting similar results for a certain combination of numbers but please that in mind

Comment: yes, you were right, there was actually a small change in graph that I  haven't noticed first, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `imag` operator in the plot.  `x_imag` is the imaginary part and is not complex.  So `imag(x_imag)` returns 0.  Change

```
stem(w, imag(x_imag), 'filled')
```

to

```
stem(w, x_imag, 'filled')
```

For the phase you want to use  `atan` for the arctangent.  `inv` perofrms the matrix inverse.  So change

```
x_phase = inv(tan(-a.*sin(w)./(1- a.*cos(w))))
```

to

```
x_phase = atan(-a.*sin(w)./(1- a.*cos(w))))
```